# How to sort the month name in the graph in python(Jan,feb...... and so on) right now it is not in ordered form

Tags: python, sorting, graph, unordered

In code I have already created a month column and groupby it according to month but the months names are not sorted. How can I do it

```
enter code here
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
bymonth = df1.groupby('Created_Month').count().reset_index()
a=bymonth['Created_Month']
b=bymonth['Customer Complaint']

plt.plot(a,b,color='g',linewidth=3,label='max complaints in Jun')
plt.xlabel('Created Month')
plt.xlabel('customer complain')
plt.title("Number of complaints monthly")
plt.text(6.25, 1000, '<--max complaint in Jun', fontsize = 12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of using an image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

convert into list and this may help,

```
from calendar import month_name
month_lookup = list(month_name)
months = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
sorted(months, key=month_lookup.index)
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do like answer #1 in [this](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/255022) thread sketches out. Add another column to your dataframe with the month number and sort the dataframe by that column.

On another note: please remember to [post code as plain text an not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).